# faster input output in c and using register keyword?

Tags: c, input, output, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have started of with coding & looking to improve my timing.Can someone tell me how can I accept input & display output faster in C? Also can I use the register variable to further optimize the program? A small simple program demonstrating fast i/p,o/p & register keyword would be very helpful!

Comment: The `register` keyword is mostly deprecated, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675072/is-the-register-keyword-still-used

Comment: If your question is “will using the `register` keyword make my program faster”, the answer is “almost certainly not”. If your question is how to make your program faster, you haven't shown the program…

Comment: `register` is "exactly as meaningful as whitespace." - [Herb Sutter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1661064/herb-sutter). See http://www.drdobbs.com/keywords-that-arent-or-comments-by-anoth/184403859

Comment: Use of `resister`, even if it was made accessing a variable 10x faster, would be swamped by the time it takes to do input/output. You need to post your IO code usage - then some serous speed improvements may be had.  Judicious use of `resister` is not the way to improve IO.