# "Type name does not allow storage class to be specified" error when passing value as argument

Tags: c++

I have been writing the foundations of an emulator for a 6502. I have a function that I want to use to set the zero and negative flags for a given register. This function is contained in a struct called `CPU`.

My code currently looks like this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdint>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;
typedef uint16_t WORD;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;

struct CPU {
   BYTE SP; // stack pointer
   WORD PC; // program counter
  
   BYTE A, X, Y; // registers

   // some more registers, flags, etc.
   
   void SetStatusFlags(BYTE register) {
      Z = (register == 0);
      N = (register & 0b10000000) > 0;
   }

   // some other functions that call this one...
};
```

This causes an error:

```
error: type name does not allow storage class to be specified
Z = (register == 0);
               ^
```

It also causes other errors concerning parentheses, although [this C++ linter](http://cpplint.appspot.com/CppLint) doesn't seem to detect any problems with such things.

This only happens if I pass the function a parameter. If I write something like this:

```cpp
void different() {
   Z = (A == 0);
   N = (A & 0b10000000) > 0;
}
```

No errors occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`register` is a (deprecated) keyword. Pick a different name for the variable.

See:

- [Register keyword in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207018/register-keyword-in-c)
- [Why was the register keyword created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456494/why-was-the-register-keyword-created)