# Registering a new command-line option

Tags: clang

I need advice about registering a new command-line option in Clang.

For example, if I want to add an simple option like `-Wregister`, which files I need to modify or what to do in general?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on this?  Just to verify, is [this](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandLine.html#writing-a-custom-parser) what you're trying to do?

Comment: Not exactly. For example, if you have a program `int main() { register int x; }` and if you use `-std=c++11` flag the compiler will output the following warning message: _'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++1z [-Wdeprecated-register]_. I want to register a new option `-Wxyz` which should instruct the compiler to check the presence of the _xyz_ specifier.

Comment: Ah so you mean the register keyword, for memory allocation, as they are asking about in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675072/is-the-register-keyword-still-used) ?

Comment: Yes. I know what the `register` specifier does, but I need an advice how to implement option like that.