# ASM register-variable from existing register-value in clang

Tags: c++, assembly, clang, x86-64, inline-assembly

I'm having slight issues with trying to use register-variables in clang-cl, on windows. I'm trying to declare a variable that simply reuses a (non-volatile) register that has been setup by a prior call. Here is a [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qvxbax357) of what I'm trying to achieve, and how it would work on GCC, but not on clang.

**The problem**

What I'm trying to do is basically the "global register variable" case. The function I'm trying to write is called from within my owns script JIT-runtime, and "RBX" contains a state-object that I need for that specific call. GCC would allow me to declare a global register variable to achieve this:

```
// Case 1 - using global register variable (only supported by GCC)
register ExecutionStateJIT* pState asm("rbx");

void resumeMultiplexGlobal(void)
{
    pState->pData = nullptr;
}
```

This is exactly what I need (all the side-effects of using such a global variable in that particular translation unit are precisely what I need). But since clang doesn't support it - what are my alternatives? I tried a few different things:

```
// Case 2 - using unassigned local register variable (Clang refuses code-gen for this)
void resumeMultiplex(void)
{
    register ExecutionStateJIT* pState asm("rbx");

    pState->pData = nullptr;
}
```

Using a local-register variable without an assignment works in GCC as well, even though if I understand the docs it's not actually supported. Clang on the other hand does not compile anything for this function - probably due to assuming an unassigned variable, and performing wonderful UB-"f*** your code" optimizations.

**Workarounds**

There are two workarounds that I found, both not quite optimal:

```
// Workaround 1 - binding as output to asm (generates unwanted preverse of rbx)
void resumeMultiplexWorkaround()
{
    register ExecutionStateJIT* pState asm("rbx");

    asm volatile(""
        : "=r" (pState)
        :
        : );

    pState->pData = nullptr;
}
```

Simply binding the unassigned variable as an output produces the same code on GCC. It also get's clang to finally emit some code, though it contains an absolutely unnecessary preservation of the RBX register - even though I purposefully tried to lie to the compiler about RBX being clobbered (but I assume output to a register-variable implicitely clobbers the register).

I could of course mov to another register:

```
// Workaround 2 - mov to another register 
// (unnecessary mov; plus if we want to be call-clobber save we'd need another non-volatile register that needs to be preserved)
void resumeMultiplexWorkaround2()
{
    register ExecutionStateJIT* pState asm("rcx");

    asm volatile("mov %0,rbx"
        : "=r" (pState)
        :
        : );

    pState->pData = nullptr;
}
```

Which is technically less instructions, but for the actual function in question, I need a call-preserved register, as it may contain function-calls.

**Wrapping it up**

So, is there any way to get an optimal code-gen for this example on clang? The actual function in question is quite large:

```
void resumeMultiplex(void)
{
    register ExecutionStateJIT* pState asm("rbx");

    asm volatile(""
        : "=&r" (pState)
        :
        : );

    auto& state = *pState;
    AE_ASSERT(state.pMultiplex);
    auto& multiplex = *state.pMultiplex;
    multiplex.SetDt(state.dt);

    AE_ASSERT(multiplex.isFullyStarted);
    AE_ASSERT(!multiplex.vSubFrames.IsEmpty());
    AE_ASSERT(!sys::isValidId(multiplex.currentFrame));

    multiplex.currentFrame = 0;
    auto& frame = *multiplex.vSubFrames.Data();

    state.pFrame = frame.pFrame;
    state.pMultiplex = frame.pMultiplex;
    state.pThis = frame.pThis;

    copyMultiplexDataImpl(frame.pFrame + 32, frame.vData.Data(), frame.vData.Size());

    //! purposefully lying to compiler here about clobbered registers, as modifications to stack are removed with the jmp
    asm volatile("mov rsp,%0"
        :
        : "o" (frame.pFrame)
        :);
    asm volatile("mov rbp,%0"
        :
        : "o" (frame.pTop)
        : );
    //! similarily, we jmp in __asm-block here, as otherwise we would get unwanted epilogue in case of non-inlined functions
    __asm
    {
        jmp frame.pAddress;
    }
}
```

So I don't want to have to code all the accesses to "state" myself in assembly.

Comment: Very related: [Why does clang behave weirdly with register variables compared to gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55648274/why-does-clang-behave-weirdly-with-register-variables-compared-to-gcc)

Comment: @chtz Thanks, already saw it. I know that global register is not supported. Local register seems to be though, so I'm asking if there is a way to achieve the same thing that GCC would, with the tools that clang supports.

Comment: You're basically trying to generate code for a custom calling convention.  This isn't supported, so you're trying to hack up something that will happen to compile to the asm you want.  This is going to be very brittle.

Comment: Also, two separate `asm` statements that `mov` to RSP then RBP from mem src operands seem dicey.  I guess neither of the source operands are likely to be locals on the stack accessed relative to RSP or RBP, probably instead `frame` will be a pointer in some other register.  But I'd be inclined to ask for `&frame` in a register and manually write the `mov rsp, [%0 + %1]` ; `mov rbp, [%0 + %2]` where `%1` and `%2` are operands like `"i" (offsetof(typeid(frame), pFrame))`, and make the `jmp` part of the same `asm volatile` statement with a `"memory"` clobber, followed by `__builtin_unreachable()`

Comment: Frankly, don't. There's probably a reason why you want that pointer in that register -- still, just make it an ordinary pointer, and when you get to the place where you need it in the register, provide some assembler code that takes your C++ pointer as a parameter. Yes, "C" is often seen as a "portable assembler"... but, there are limits.

Comment: @PeterCordes You are right about the custom calling convention - though in GCC with the global register, it would work out nicely (as RBX for my convention is kind of a global - though in a register as it's accessed often). Regarding RSP+RBP - this is part of a stackfull-coroutine resume routine, to actually restore both stack and frame-pointer (that I need internally) to where I can resume execution. This code is production-proven, mind you, even that asm-variant has already been validated against an extensive test-suite. Its primarily about optimization at that point.

Comment: @ChristianStieber The reason here is mainly performance. This routine is called many times per frame, so I want it to be as fast as possible. Still, if it's not possible, I can just use a normal pointer. The variant using a c++-compiler is still way faster than if I wrote the assembly myself, as I won't realistically inline all the related call that way.

Comment: @PeterCordes Nevermind, I just understood that what you meant is that it's not guaranteed that frame is not part of the current stack. So while it may work, even in all my test cases, it could break under different circumstances. Will try out what you suggested.

Comment: *contains an absolutely unnecessary preservation of the RBX register - even though I purposefully tried to lie to the compiler about RBX being clobbered (but I assume output to a register-variable implicitely clobbers the register).* - Register preservation is to make the containing function follow the calling convention.  You have a function with asm that "produces" an output in RBX, according to what you told the compiler with the asm constraints.  GNU C inline asm just tells the compiler which registers are involved, the compiler does reg alloc for the containing function (after inlining).

Comment: @PeterCordes What I mean is - unnecessary for my use-case. And I can prevent the compiler from seeing a register being modified with regular extended asm - for setting RSP/RBP I do not add it to the clobber list on purpose, which prevents generating code for preserving eigther registers. But if that's not possible for register variables, I'll have to life with it.

Comment: Re: *The variant using a c++-compiler is still way faster than if I wrote the assembly myself*: I guess that should make you reconsider to micro-optimize whether certain variables are stored globally in registers. If the compiler is able to inline most of the code, it will keep important variables in registers anyways. Also, if you always pass the variable at the same position (or a implicit `this`-pointer inside a class), it will likely be kept in the same register, if the compiler sees that the called method does not overwrite the register.

Comment: @chtz Part of the code is generated by my own compiler for my own script-language in a JIT-style fashion - probably didn't make that clear enough. So there is no program-wide optimization possible, and doing certain "micro"-optimizations like storing an essential "state" object, that is accessed everywhere in that JIT-code in a global register, makes more sense there. Those methods I showed cannot be inlined for the same reason, as they are called from that JIT-ed code.