# Will inlining a function containing another function cause the inner one to be inlined?

Tags: c++, function, inline

Suppose we have a class member function that calls a free function:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  void func1() {func2();}
};
```

I'm curious to know if there is a possibility that the compiler will inline the function inside (`func2`) because `func1` is inline?

Comment: The compiler doesn't even necessarily inline `func1`. C++ `inline` (whether explicit or implicit) has virtually nothing to do with the optimization known as inlining.

Comment: Marking function as `inline` is not about inlining, but rather about linking rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact `func2` is inlined or not depends on how *complex* is func2.
The fact func1 is inlined or not depends on how complex it will be after f2 expansion (if any).

inlining is essentially a compiler optimization that does not depend on the fact a function definition is inlined-in-source (hence repeatble) or not.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no basis and no reason for such connection to exist. The matter of inlining the inner function call is independent from the matter of inlining the enclosing function calls.

Addressing your question: the *possibility* that the inner call will be inlined is there, of course, but again, it is in no way related to whether the outer function is inlined or not.

It should be noted that compiler's decision-making algorithm that decide whether to inline functions will generally be smart enough to avoid excessive code bloat, i.e. to avoid generation of exceedingly long functions. This means that in some cases inlining the outer function might mean that the inner calls will *not* be inlined. And vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the compiler, and the circumstances.

Compilers decide to inline functions based on:

1. Visibility of the code. Obviously, it can't inline a function that the compiler has no source code for [1].
2. Size of the code. Large functions are less likely to be inlined than small functions.
3. The number of calls to a function. If it's a small function, it may be called hundreds of times and still be inlined, a large function called more than once is probably NOT inlined. At least GCC has a special case for "function only called once" - where it inlines even huge functions under that special case.

So, in this case, if `func2` is visible to the compiler, and is small enough that the compiler sees it OK to inline, then it probably will be.

Answer (score 0):

No, having `func1` inline will not automatically *cause* `func2` to be inlined; but there is *always* a possibility that the compiler will inline `func2`, independently of whether `func1` is inline or not.

Answer (score 0):

Inlining behavior is completely implementation defined. The compiler is free to ignore or respect or to use its own heuristics to determine what is should do.

Sometimes compilers do it when not asked: [When do compilers inline C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443982/when-do-compilers-inline-c-code)

Sometimes compilers ignore it: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35432/inline-functions-in-c-whats-the-point