# Does inlining depend on the call site?

Tags: c++, optimization, inline

Is there a C++ code sample and a compiler, in which a function is called twice in a single translation unit, and at one call site the function is inlined, but not at the other? So you have one function, and two call sites, and the compiler decides whether to inline it based on the call site.

- This should be done without `#pragma`s. Just pure C++.
- Any working example will do, e.g. in [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/). I am asking this as a puzzle.

Comment: Related: [When do compilers inline functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443982/when-do-compilers-inline-functions)

Comment: The approach for inlining functions (or not) is a property of the implementation, not something that is specified in the standard.   Different implementations do it differently, because they measure/gauge the costs and benefits differently.   The approach used can also be affected by optimisation settings,  content of the function being called (e.g. some compilers won't inline a function over a certain size, some [older] compilers won't inline a function with a `switch` statement).

Comment: Just to confirm, are you looking for a positive example (like on godbolt or something) of such a thing happening?  Because, fair warning, even if you get what you're looking for, it may be something of a _unicorn_ in that just because you found one example doesn't mean that other similar examples will behave the same way.  It's completely up to the compiler.

Comment: I am asking out of curiosity. A _unicorn_ example will do.

Comment: I can imagine cases where inlining a function in one circumstance would blow the instruction cache while performing better inlined everywhere else. Whether the compiler will play mix-n-match, I don't know for sure. Can't think of a reason why it wouldn't, though.

Comment: PGO (Profile Guided Optimization; you run instrumented code through "typical" workloads, then use the collected stats to guide optimization in a second compilation pass) would almost certainly be a good source of this sort of discrepancy. More aggressive inlining for the hot code, with uses of the function coming from the cold sections not bothering to inline would make perfect sense.

Comment: Any simple getter class member defined in a .cc, it will be inlined in that .cc very likely and called in another .cc.

Comment: Naturally. But, we are talking about a C++ code sample in a single translation unit here.

Comment: @Dr.Gut *"in a single translation unit here"* -- The question says no such thing... *(I find call sites in different translation units a very good match to the question as it is currently written.)*

Comment: *"We are talking about one single translation unit,"* -- This wording strikes me as a strange way to introduce a restriction. I'm going to take a stab at writing it better while preserving the meaning.